# How can I parameterize make targets?

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

I have the following targets in my makefile to generate icons for my Android app:

```
base_icon := icon-base.png

Icon-ldpi.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize 36x36 -unsharp 1x4 $@

Icon-mdpi.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize 48x48 -unsharp 1x4 $@

Icon-hdpi.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize 72x72 -unsharp 1x4 $@

Icon-xhdpi.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize 96x96 -unsharp 1x4 $@

Icon-xxhdpi.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize 144x144 -unsharp 1x4 $@

Icon-xxxhdpi.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize 192x192 -unsharp 1x4 $@

icons_android: \
    Icon-ldpi.png \
    Icon-mdpi.png \
    Icon-hdpi.png \
    Icon-xhdpi.png \
    Icon-xxhdpi.png \
    Icon-xxxhdpi.png
```

How can I make this more elegant without repeating the convert instructions over and over again?

What I was looking for was having some sort of a parameterized target:

```
Icon-%.png: $(base_icon)
    convert $< -resize $(size) -unsharp 1x4 $@
```

But I am not certain how to lookup the `$(size)` for the given icon. Is there some sorts of a map that I can define in a Makefile and lookup in the target?

Comment: You could probably do it if you embedded the size (e.g. 72) into the name.  It is a lot harder to convert `l` to 32, `m` to 48, `h` to 72, `xh` to 96, `xxh` to 144, and `xxxh` to 192.

Comment: Sadly Android requires the filenames to be exactly like stated above.

Comment: That's mildly irksome (that Android requires the names as shown).  On a Unix environment, I'd write a shell script that did the name mapping.  It seems likely that you'll always need to regenerate all the icons (unless, I suppose, just one of them got deleted; if the master file changes, they all need to be recreated), so I'd probably just run the script with the basic name and regenerate all the files each time.  I'm not sure if that helps you with an Android development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following example, although it's not perfect,

```
base_icon :=  icon-base.png

define icon_template
Icon-$(1).png: $$(base_icon)
        convert $$< -resize $(2) -unsharp 1x4 $$@
icons_android: Icon-$(1).png
endef

$(eval $(call icon_template,ldpi,36x36))
$(eval $(call icon_template,mdpi,48x48))
$(eval $(call icon_template,hdpi,72x72))
```

Comment: Already much better than what I got, thanks! Now if only there was a way to build that `icons_android` target dynamically...

Comment: Sure. BTW, what does "build target dynamically" mean?

Comment: Not repeatedly listing all the icons again, but rather somehow create a list from the `icon_template`calls and use that.

Comment: Bravo! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!